# Пропустить итерацию чтения файла Perl

Tags: perl

Добрый день!

вот рабочий код (пропуск строки по условию):

```
while($testGroup = readdir(OFFLINES))
{
print $offlinesDir."\\".$testGroup;

next if not ($testGroup =~ m/Test_Group/); 
...
}
```

если *next* вставить внутрь условия **if(){..}** то пропуска не будет. Я почитал доки и не понимаю почему два одинаковых варианта работают по разному.

Comment: то есть, если написать так

    if not ($testGroup =~ m/Test_Group/) {next;}

то не работает?

Comment: вы правы, не работает

Comment: дайте больше кода. Что бы можно было повторить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и так:

```
my @files = grep { !/$MASK/ } readdir $dirh;
```

Или так:

```
my @files = map { !/$MASK/ ? $_ : () } readdir $dirh;
```

Comment: @klopp также вопроса не читаем?

Comment: Читаем, но не понимаем что не работает. У меня вариант ТС работает :) В разных версиях:

    if( not $file =~ /$MASK/ ) { next; }

    if( !($file =~ /$MASK/) ) { next; }

    unless( $file =~ /$MASK/ ) { next; }

    if( $file !~ /$MASK/ ) { next; }

Comment: у меня также работает. и я часть этого привел в комментариях. Но как Ваш ответ отвечает на вопрос вопрошающего? правильный ответ - никак.

Comment: Ну так к тому и речь: мы вариантов кода накидали, а "неправильного" так и не видим :)

Comment: я написал 

     if($testGroup !~ m/Test_Group/)
    {
        next;
    }

и не работает

Comment: а посоветуйте что почитать(не совсем новичку) по *Perl*? Я в первый раз вижу конструкции выше с **grep** и **map**

Comment: Начните с классики - [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/index.html). [читать онлайн без смс и лабуды](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_00.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
opendir OFFLINES, './';
while(my $testGroup = readdir(OFFLINES))
{
    next if $testGroup !~ m/parse.pl/; 
    say $testGroup;
}
```

Всё работает.

Comment: и как это отвечает на вопрос @voipp?

Comment: if ($testGroup !~ m/parse.pl/) {next;}

Так тоже работает.

Comment: конечно работает. и ещё десяток вариантов могу написать, которые будут работать (например с unless). интересно ведь почему у вопрошающего не работает.

Comment: Надо смотреть на код. Возможно, дело в приоритете `not` и порядке операций.

Comment: Ответов до фига дали - выбираем и юзаем!)))

Comment: я написал 

     if($testGroup !~ m/Test_Group/)
    {
        next;
    }

и не работает

Comment: Проверьте, точно-ли вы в этот блок попадаете (print 1 перед next, к примеру).

Comment: все, бага исправлена